# Our Exchange Server (Office 365/online) is configured, to archive mails by sending a copy to mbx-8423...@archive.example.com. Where do I change this?

Tags: configuration, exchange-server, archive

All e-mails in our exchange server are getting archived by sending a copy. I have inherited the service and have not received any further information about the configuration.

I would be pleased to receive a hint on how to solve the problem.

I have checked the configuration options in the admin interface of exchange. I could not find the appropriate setting options.